# Refreshing ListView after Inserting New Item into MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, listview, refresh

I have attempted so many way and recommendations but my code is just not going right.  Here is what I have done.  What code needs to be added so that after I new item is added the, item shows up in the list?

Here is the context:

In the Action Bar, there is an "Add Item" Button.  The dialog opens, and in the onclick in the dialog, it inserts a word that you have typed in a single field into a database (MySQL), dismisses the dialog, then ... this is where my troubles are  .... nothing.

Edit:  I have tried this -- yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
I simply do not know where to put it or how to use it because it doesn't change anything.

```
 public class Items extends ListActivity {


List<String> items = null;
String NewItem;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    items = new ArrayList<String>();

    new task().execute();

}

 // Class that sets up ListView and populates from database on initial Activity Load
class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


        // HttpPost ... etc
                    // BufferRedReader .. etc 


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        String item;
        try {
            // JSON Stuff
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {


 //  Here is where ListView is set up when Activity/page first starts

        listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Rate.class);
                i.putExtra("name", items.get(arg2));
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Items.this, R.layout.list, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Add_Item:

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Items.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.insert_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Insert Item");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();

        final EditText etInsert = (EditText) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.etInsertItem);

        Button bInsert = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bInsert);
        bInsert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                NewItem = etInsert.getText().toString();
                new insertTask().execute();


                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        return true;
    case R.id.About:

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


 // This Class is the "inserting item" task inside the dialog

class insertTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


        try {
            // HttpPost Stuff ... running insert Script to Database here

        } 

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

            // Add ListView Refresh Here????

    }


}
 }
```

Comment: Please give only required code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` directly after you update the data. That should be enough. You also can put `notifyDataSetChanged();` in the adapter itself, on the line after you update the model data.

Btw. I don't see in your code the list update. You have to update the model data of the list before you call `notifyDataSetChanged();`, of course.

Comment: Would "updating the data" be the HttpPost?  And if so, this means "After" would be the onPostExecute?

Comment: Your list has an array or list containing the model data. You need some method like "setData(newData)" or "updateData(newData)" in the adapter to put different model data in the list. After you set/update the model data, you call notifyDataSetChanged to notify the list that the model data was updated and it has to be redrawn. In which context you do this (AsynchTask, or whatever) is not important.

Comment: Ok, I see where this is going wrong.  I am missing a step.  Would it be bad practice to run the first task in the postExecute of the second task?  That re-updates the list.  Or should I just update the single item...

Comment: You should open a new thread with a concrete question, about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in your `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Thanks;  I have seen this method posted every where and have tried it many times.  It does nothing... unless I am using it wrong or putting it in the wrong spot?

Comment: I believe I have, but I am willing to again; where would I put it -- in the onPostExecute method of the task?

Comment: yes, when you finish work, call for refresh ListView but for what you have two AsyncTasks?

Comment: I do, and I know there is probably a better way to do that?  The first populates the ListView when the user first enters the activity.  The second is for an HttpPost that will insert a new item.  In other words, I have two HttpPost doing different things, and a task for each.

Comment: aha ok so how i meant, you should use this method when you finish work so get new data and then update them.

Comment: I just asked that exact question in another answer.  And that actually works!  But is that good practice?   seems like reloading/re-downloading the whole list data to add a single item wastes resources and battery, and potentially is slower? Otherwise, I am fine with it!

Comment: so you should decide to use most efficient approach. so if it wastes resouces and battery so do not use it.

Answer (score 1):

The `list<String> items` is used in the adapter to get the data for the ListItems. You need to add the new Item to this list i.e. `items` and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in the `onPostExecute()` of the `insertTask` asyncTask.